# Query on Entity Relationship diagram

Tags: oop, uml, ooad

Below is the ER diagram with relation among 5 different entities.

[image]

My question:

1)
Each of these 5 entities a `class` as per OOP terminology?

2)
Can you help me understand the meaning of relation(different types of lines) among these 5 entities? Line with a little bubble/ with an angular shape /text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an UML diagram at all, but an entity-relationship (E-R) diagram and typically shows the DB design. You can easily google it to find the detailed notstional rules, I could quickly find this page:

http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b12021/img/entity_d.gif&imgrefurl=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b12021/dev.htm&h=1780&w=1556&tbnid=vbXfAtrAAIq5_M:&zoom=1&tbnh=97&tbnw=85&usg=__vyr0LMggQHqYtI8Q6Ix-722jJwg=&docid=3LbfUSlxwqfpMM&client=firefox-a&sa=X&ei=iX1HU5awEImN7Qbf6IGwDg&ved=0CEsQ9QEwBA&dur=1439

If you want to model DB in UML, you can still do it, using class diagram and eventually restricting permited relationships to those available in non-OO modelling.

Comment: Do we generally use ER diagram to display the Database design? when you say DB?

Comment: There is no "general rule" and this decision depends on the context: tools you have available, surrounding project conditions and its nature, your teams skills and finally personal preference. Both options are valid. 

If you plan to draw some other UML diagrams, the logical decision is to use classes for the DB modelling and keep everything in one place. 

If the project is relativelly small and you only need to make this single diagram and hand it to your DB Expert, ER would be fine.